# How to use variable pattern in angularjs for mongodb

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, mongodb

I want to do a find() query on mongodb using angular-js and by using regex.
But i am not able use a variable pattern in regex.

Below is the code for the same.

```
var User=mongoose.model('User');
exports.searchname = function(req,res){

var pattern="hello";
User.find({displayName:{$regex:"/"+pattern+"/",$options:"si"}}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {

        res.json({Data:data});
    }
});
```

I also tried using /pattern/ instead of "/"+pattern+"/". It also didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** object for your query:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('hello', 'i'); /* or new RegExp(/hello/, 'i'); */
User.find({displayName: pattern}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {

        res.json({Data:data});
    }
});
```